# OAuth 2.0 Implementation - Should Auth Server and Resource Server Have Separate Databases?

Tags: entity-framework, oauth, entity-framework-migrations

The official Specifications probably don't mention this or regard it as "outside the scope of this specification".

Say we have decided to separate the auth and resource servers.

In practice, why would we want the resource and auth servers to access the same database, or why would we want to keep two separate databases - one for each server?

I'm writing this question because of Entity Framework. If I shared the same database between both sites, I figure migrations would conflict even if the auth server only touched account-related tables and the resource server only touched data (POCO) tables. (I actually haven't tried this out yet, but I don't want to waste time experimenting, so I want to hear from someone who has come across this.)

But if I separate the databases, I lose the foreign key relationship between user and the data [s]he owns - but is that even necessary? It feels like it's one of those "we did that just because" practices.

Answer (score 0):

To combine them and use migrations, you'd need to have a DbContext for migrations that includes all the types used by either auth or resource servers, and use that for scaffolding migrations. This seems to be a common practice for those that require multiple contexts and want to use migrations; it's worked well for me so far.

As far as the foreign key constraints, they're just that - constraints. They enforce your business rules (that Foo.Bar must contain a value that exists in Baz.Bar) at the database level. Whether or not this is necessary really depends on your use case. Very few things are done "just because", though many things are done without full understanding - "because I saw it done like this somewhere else". The somewhere else (or wherever they copied it from, etc.) may have a perfectly valid reason, which may or may not apply to your use case.